# Trouble generating MASReceipt during development

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mac-app-store

I am working on developing a Mac application that has an in app purchase. I have done this before on iOS, but I cannot get it to work with the Mac app. After doing some research it looks like I will have to get and validate a receipt from the Mac App Store before this will work.

I believe that I have followed the steps to do this correctly,

1.) Build the app in Xcode.
2.) Launch the app through finder
3.) When prompted sign in with a TestUser account created in iTunesConnect
4.) The app closes with the error message

```
“AppName” is damaged and can’t be opened. Delete “AppName” and download it again from the App Store.
```

When I open up the bundle though I do not see the _MASReceipt/receipt folder and file - and I am still getting invalid product identifiers from StoreKit.

Comment: I'd figure you've solved this by now? Care to share the solution?

Comment: Actually, I didn't. This was a time-sensitive project and we ended up creating a free and paid version because we could not debug it after a week of trying. Projects since then have worked with no issues. So I have no idea what the problem was.

Comment: I no longer have access to the files either to test if you solution worked - we did try restarting several times though which I assume would have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

These steps seems to work for me the last time this happened:

1. Log out from Mac App Store.
2. Force quit `storeagent` and `softwareupdated` processes.
3. Try double-clicking the app to start it again.